# Characteristics of a Prime Number

Tags: prime-numbers

Will it be true if I say "If a number is not divisible by any of the numbers from $2$ to $9$, it is a prime number." If no, can you mention some numbers which defy this statement?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Consider $121$, $143$, and $169$

Comment: Thank You J. W. Tanner and JP3112.

Comment: On reading the quoted statement more carefully, I see it says $1$ to $9$.  There is no number not divisible by $1$, so the statement is vacuously true

Comment: My bad ;P Should be 2-9. I'll fix it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The statement you quoted is not true.

There are infinitely many composite numbers not divisible by any number from $2$ to $9$.

Examples include $11\times11$, $11\times11\times 11$, $11\times11\times11\times11$, ...,

$13\times13$, $13\times13\times13$, $13\times13\times13\times13$, ..., $17\times17$, ... $19\times19$, ...,

besides $11\times13$, $11\times17$, $11\times19$, ... $13\times17$, ....

Answer (score 0):

2 is divisible by a number from 1 to 9 but it is prime. The definition that I like to go with for prime numbers is 'a number is prime iff it has exactly 2 divisors'.